# Strange jQuery syntax - jEditable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jeditable

What does this statement do :

```
var row =   jQuery("../../td",link) ; // $(link).parent().parent().children();
```

link = button.evenLink (a button with css class named 'eventLink'). And this button is inside a cell of an editable table.

I'm trying to use the jEditable plugin and jQuery UI together, but this plugin seems to be incompatible with jQuery 1.7.* which is required for jquery UI.

The problem seems to be the statement above in the ***tableEditor.js*** file. I tried replacing it with the parent selector(as shown in the commented code above, but it probably doesn't return the same object). So, can anyone give an idea about, **what exactly the above statement returns OR what should/can be done to make this plugin work with the jquery UI ?** Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the tableEditor uses jquery 1.0.3 version, so it might create problems in other sections as well which you have not yet found out. So i suggest you use some other plugins thats compatible with latest version of jquery. 
One option could be using [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

```
var row =   jQuery("../../td",link) ;
```

This code is of format:

```
$(expr, context)
```

It accepts a string containing a CSS selector, or basic XPath, which is then used to match a set of elements with the context of the specified DOM element, or document.

```
expr (String): An expression to search with.
context (Element): A DOM Element, or Document, representing the base context.
```

And jquery doesnot support XPath selector syntax anymore.

Comment: Ok. But, what about that code, what does it return?
And even the jqGrid, seems like a 'work in progress', as it appears from the comments.